# spring data rest with sts package

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am creating a java starter at sts ..simple project 
Employee class in `com.entities`
EmployRepository in `com.repository` extends CrudRepository
EmployeeApi in `com.employee` the `main()`

When I have the classes in the packages and I try to run the application and brows to `localhost:8080` I don't get the entity link.

I only get the profile as below

```
 {
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

While the expected result is

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "employees" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

However when I put the classes all in one package I get the output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class):

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in
>   a root package above other classes. The @SpringBootApplication
>   annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly
>   defines a base “search package” for certain items. For example, if you
>   are writing a JPA application, the package of the
>   @SpringBootApplication annotated class is used to search for @Entity
>   items. Using a root package also allows component scan to apply only
>   on your project.

To sum it up: By default repositories and entities are searched in your application classes package and subpackeges. This behaviour can be changed with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "this.is.a.package.name")`.

Move your entities and repositories to subpackages of your application class or add their packages to the scan path.

Comment: that how i have it

Comment: thats how i have it 
com.employee for the application main
com.employee.entities for entity classes
com.employee.employeeRepo for repository 
yet when i have it organized this way and run the application and brows to localhost:8080 
it was not displaying the json for the entity it was only the profile
but when i have all in one package it worked fine ..

Comment: @MomoShaheen then update your question for other readers, please. In your original question your package names are `com.entities`, `com.repository`, etc, this case would've been solved by this answer. Furthermore please provide some more details when you have the right package structure, maybe a repository/entity example and your application class.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** I think the *problem is with how you are organizing your code*.

**Suggestion** You need to check your folder structure carefully.

**Example**

```
    ->src
    ----->main
    ---------->java
              |-------->com.example.spring
              |-------->com.example.spring.entities
                        |------>Employee.java
              |-------->com.example.spring.repositories
                        |------>EmployeeRepo.java
              |--------->DemoApplication.java
```

--> Check out the following [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lupmx.png)! <--

[Sample directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lupmx.png)

Comment: here is the package explorer of my STS
[package explorer ](C:\Users\mohamed\Desktop)